# Ruby on Rails: After saving model.find(params[:id]) into class variable, something is going wrong in show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, attributes, parameters

I have a next/back method that uses params[:id] to navigate. Upon my next call, I increase id by one after taking it from the url to allow for a next call. This as far as I can tell is fine.

My issue is displaying the data I am pulling in. I have saved the required object (question_basic) in a variable @question_basic that I can display properly in the view using inspect, @questions_basic.inspect. This is fine, except the output is ugly and I only need one column/attribute called questiontxt. I have tried @questions_basic.questiontxt among a lot of other things, and all I get is nil. The only thing that displays anything is inspect.

Here is my output:

```
#<QuestionsBasic ID: 5, question_group_id: 1, question_subgroup_id: 1, company_id: 1, questiontxt: "Ich führe gerne persönliche Gespräche mit anderen ...">
```

How can I pull that questiontxt attribute out of this model? I've tried everything and I can't manage to do it. Am I mapping it wrong?

```
def index
        @i = 1
        @userprojid = current_user.project_id
        @compid= QuestionsBasic.connection.select_all("SELECT company_id FROM project WHERE ID ="+@userprojid.to_s)
        @compid= @compid.rows[0][0]
        @questions_basic = QuestionsBasic.connection.select_all("SELECT questiontxt FROM questions_basic WHERE company_id="+@compid.to_s)
    end

def new
end

def create
    @questions_basic = QuestionsBasic.new(questions_basic_params)
    @questions_basic.save
end

def show

    @questions_basic = QuestionsBasic.find(params[:id])


    @i = params[:id].to_i + 1
end






class QuestionsBasic < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :id, :questions_group_id, :question_subgroup_id, :company_id, :questiontxt
self.table_name = 'questions_basic'
self.primary_key = :ID

has_many :question_cat_basics, :class_name => 'QuestionCatBasic'
belongs_to :question_group, :class_name => 'QuestionGroup', :foreign_key => :question_group_id
belongs_to :question_subgroup, :class_name => 'QuestionSubgroup', :foreign_key => :question_subgroup_id
belongs_to :company, :class_name => 'Company', :foreign_key => :company_id




end






                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h1 class="title_align">Question Form 1</h1>
                    <div class="question_frame" align="center">
                        <p class="question">

                                <%= @questions_basic.inspect %>

                        </p>
<% form_tag({ :controller => "questions_basic", :action => "create"} ) do  %>
<%= hidden_field_tag(:user_id, current_user.id) %>
  <table class="answer">
  <tr>

</tr>
  </table>
  <% end %>
   <p class="extra_info">
                            <span><input type="checkbox" name="extra_important" value="very important" />
                                                                    This question is very important.</span>
                            <span><input type="checkbox" name="extra_skip" value="skip" />
                                                                        I cannot answer this question.</s>
    </p>
 <div class="buttons">

                        <%= form_tag(questions_basic_path(@i), method: "post") do %>
                        <%= submit_tag("next") %>
</div>
<% end %>
 <div class="buttons">
                        <%= form_tag(questions_basic_path(@i-2), method: "post") do %>
                        <%= submit_tag("previous") %>
```

I got nil for @questions_basic.questiontxt.inspect

for @questions_basic.attributes.inspect I got
{"ID"=>6, "question_group_id"=>1, "question_subgroup_id"=>2, "company_id"=>1, "questiontxt"=>"Ich fokussiere mich in den Vertriebsgesprächen ausgiebig auf Up- und Cross-Selling."}

Comment: `@questions_basic.questiontxt ` should Just Work... can you show us the code where you try to use that in your view? (Note: edit your question and put it in there, don't put code in comments because the formatting is dreadful and hard to read :) )

Comment: Hi Taryn, I added the view, I took out some of the noisey html. Notice the <p class="question">

                                <%= @questions_basic.inspect %>

                        </p>

Comment: This line is blank when I try (@questions_basic.questiontxt), nothing displayed.

Comment: try `@questions_basic.questiontxt.inspect` and see what happens... also `@questions_basic.attributes.inspect`

Comment: Tried both, updated the original question

Comment: I got it! 

<%= @questions_basic.attributes.values[4]%>

Thank you for the .attributes tip! I can't help but feel however that something is horrendously wrong because of @questions_basic.questiontxt not working.

Comment: yeah it's pretty odd that it isn't recognising the attribute name... do you have something weird on your model that's overriding it or something? (looking) oh wait you do! Why do you have `attr_accessor` in your model? you shouldn't need that line of code at all - your attributes already come automatically with accessors by way of * rails magic * <- just imagine these are magic sparkles ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so now we've worked through the discussion it seems that the issue is this line of code in your model:

```
attr_accessor :id, :questions_group_id, :question_subgroup_id, :company_id, :questiontxt
```

In Rails, you don't have to define the attributes of a model - Rails is smart enough to inspect the columns in the database table and make up accessors for all of them (that's both readers and writers). By adding the above line of code, you are overwriting the rails-standard ones and Rails is getting confused... (well it's not, but it's doing something that confuses us).

Remove that line of code and you should be good to go.

Comment: Worked like a charm... I'm too used to defining getters/setters in spring. Thanks Taryn!